# Getting the wrong chinese string in search query result!! Magento 1

Tags: magento-1.9, catalogsearch, querystring, product-sorting

I have a store in chinese language. When I search for any product it works fine.
But when I sort the result page by sku, name or price it does not work. It seems that I've got the wrong url for sorting.

Please help me!!!! How can I get the proper string url for the sorting option?

Please see the screenshot!!

[image]

Answer (score 3, accepted):

**app/design/frontend/[Magento theme Folder]/template/catalog/product/list/toolbar.phtml**

**Goto: 82 Line or search getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>**

from

```
<label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
           <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
           <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
               <option value="<?php echo $this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc') ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                   <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
               </option>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           </select>
```

to

```
<label><?php echo $this->__('Sort By') ?></label>
           <select onchange="setLocation(this.value)">
           <?php foreach($this->getAvailableOrders() as $_key=>$_order): ?>
               <option value="<?php echo urldecode($this->getOrderUrl($_key, 'asc')) ?>"<?php if($this->isOrderCurrent($_key)): ?> selected="selected"<?php endif; ?>>
                   <?php echo $this->__($_order) ?>
               </option>
           <?php endforeach; ?>
           </select>
```

Comment: Thank You very much.You saved my lots of time.....!!!!!!!